# Can I use this domain name safely?

Tags: web, dns, subdomain

I own, or rather my company owns a domain name say **`john.com`**. My main server is accessed from **`john.com`**.

I wish to setup a server that will communicate with my main server on **`guys.john.com`**.
Can I do this safely without risking complications of a domain name clash or copyright brouhaha? especially since I'm not registering **`guys.john.com`**.

Is **`guys.john.com`** even a valid format for a domain name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`guys.john.com` is a perfectly valid name. Whoever controls `john.com` can delegate it to you. You cannot have `guys.john.com` without the active cooperation of the holder of `john.com`.

Comment: But do I need to buy guys.john.com if john.com belongs to me?

Comment: No, then you can just set it up. If you have `john.com`, you control that and all names under it. So you could _sell_ `guys.john.com`, in theory.

Comment: mmm, sounds lucrative..lol..thanks a bunch. Was having issues with a support guy at mochahost and one of them was trying to convince me that I couldn't access guys.john.com, except I registered it...as in bought it. But I didn't believe it. Thanks for confirming all that for me!